# How can I lock the tail / pointer / anchor of a callout shape in place when moving the text box?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to annotate an image on my slide with callout shapes (or "speech bubbles").

I place the shape, and position the tail to point to the area of interest on the image.

Then I start typing text, and usually have to resize/move the textbox. This, for whatever reason, also moves the tail/pointer around, making this process kind of unusable for me.

I there a way to move the textbox part of the callout shape without changing where it points to?

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too. No one has understood the question. We want the tail to NOT move when we move the text part. Need to ANCHOR it on the page or to an object.

Comment: crazy isn't it 

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found a general solution so far and this is probably not the workflow you're looking for but you can do it like this:

1. Right-click on the shape
2. Select **Format Shape**
3. Select **Text Options**
4. Switch to the **Text Box** tab ([image: the Text Box tab])
5. Select either *Do not Autofit* or *Shrink text to overflow*

Comment: The tail is still moved when I move the callout, even with this setting.

Comment: @Zalumon I am sorry I missunderstood you. I thought you have trouble with longer texts changing the size of it.

Comment: @Zalumon I guess you know that already but you can move the tail dragging the yellow circle on it.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it, click onto the bubble outline so the bubble highlights then click on the text then click on the outline of the bubble again and it moves but the pointer stays pointing :-)

Comment: I don't get it. Care to provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this.

Instead of using the "callout" shape, create a group which includes:

1. Rectangle (with text in it)
2. line snapped to the rectangle
3. very small circle, snapped to the other side of the line

when you move the rectangle - the circle will stay in place with the other
side of the line.
when you move the circle - the line follows it without moving the rectangle